# XNA Texture2D.FromStream returns color channels ocasionally off by 1

Tags: c#, xna, textures

I'm currently loading and saving `Texture2D`s used as mapped images into a database so they can be preloaded later. Each color channel needs to be the precise color it was when saved after loading. The problem is `Texture2D.FromStream` sometimes returns incorrect color channels that are *sometimes* off by 1 or so. This is unacceptable as the mapped colors are useless if they are incorrect.

The example below provides a situation where an RGB of 255 is changed to an RGB of 254 when the alpha is set at 100. When setting the alpha to 1 or 255 they return as 255 correctly, other alpha values cause the same issue as 100.

```
Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, 20, 20, false, SurfaceFormat.Color);
Color[] data = new Color[tex.Width * tex.Height];
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) {
    data[i] = new Color(255, 255, 255, 100);
}
tex.SetData<Color>(data);
using (Stream stream = File.Open("TestAlpha.png", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)) {
    tex.SaveAsPng(stream, tex.Width, tex.Height);
    stream.Position = 0;
    tex = Texture2D.FromStream(GraphicsDevice, stream);
    tex.GetData<Color>(data);
    Console.WriteLine(data[0]); // Returns (R:254 G:254 B:254 A:100)
}
```

I have confirmed the png has the correct RGB of 255 when looking at the saved image in Paint.NET so it can only be something caused during `Texture2D.FromStream`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did not find the cause of `Texture2D.FromStream`'s issue but I found an all-around better way to load `Texture2D`s. In this case I load GDI `Bitmap` from the stream instead, take its data, and transfer it over to a newly created `Texture2D`.

I plan on using this whether or not `Texture2D.FromSteam` is fixable but I'd still love to know if anyone knows what's going on with it.

For those of you who are new, make sure to include `System.Drawing` as a reference as its not present in XNA projects by default.

```
public static unsafe Texture2D FromStream(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice, Stream stream) {
    // Load through GDI Bitmap because it doesn't cause issues with alpha
    using (Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) Bitmap.FromStream(stream)) {
        // Create a texture and array to output the bitmap to
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(graphicsDevice,
            bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, false, SurfaceFormat.Color);
        Color[] data = new Color[bitmap.Width * bitmap.Height];

        // Get the pixels from the bitmap
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
        BitmapData bmpData = bitmap.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
            PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        // Write the pixels to the data buffer
        byte* ptr = (byte*) bmpData.Scan0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) {
            // Go through every color and reverse red and blue channels
            data[i] = new Color(ptr[2], ptr[1], ptr[0], ptr[3]);
            ptr += 4;
        }

        bitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);

        // Assign the data to the texture
        texture.SetData<Color>(data);

        // Fun fact: All this extra work is actually 50% faster than
        // Texture2D.FromStream! It's not only broken, but slow as well.

        return texture;
    }
}
```